# Threads and listener instance issue

Tags: android

I am having a strange behavior with threads and a `onclick listener instance in some phones (strange that its not by android version, have test it in a GalaxyII with android 4.03 and work, in a Samsumg Galaxy Tab with 3.2 works fine and in a HTC EVO Design 4G with android 4.03 and a HTC EVO 4G with android 2.3.3 doesn't work) so here is the issue:

I have a async class that calls a web service and blocks the screen until the service finishes, then the thread notifies the UI that the service call is finished so the UI shows a modal screen making a `addView(GenerateView)` to the activity. That works fine until I need to avoid the multiple clicks in the button that triggers the action because multiple views are adding to the activity. So I implement a custom `OnClickListener` like this:

```
public abstract class OnOneClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private boolean clickable;

    public OnOneClickListener(){
        clickable = true;
    }

   public final void onClick(View v) {
       if (clickable) {
           clickable = false;
           onOneClick(v);
       }
   }

   public abstract void onOneClick(View v);

   public void reset() {
       clickable = true;
   }
}
```

So I implement the custom `onclick`, block the clickabilty of the button, call the web service and when it finishes in the function that creates and returns the view to add to the activity as a modal windows calls `reset()` and allows the click in button again. That function receives the instance of the class by parameters. That works like a charm in the phone that mentioned before but in the HTCs when i debug can see that the `OnOneClickListener()` function modify the clickable variable and the `reset()` function doesn't see it!! and it happens in the other way too, like if the call of the functions where in two different instances of the class and it NOT!! and thats just one issue that im having with HTCs and threads, the most incredible one.

So here goes my questions:

- Is some knowed  issues with HTCs and threads??
- Is there some work around?? (Im using AsyncTask to make the calls and it works perfect until now)

In fact anything that you can tell me that help me understand where is the fail will be very helpful because it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lucky it works on some phones, because it does not have to. If you change `clickable` field on one thread, you should explicitly synchronize for the other thread to see the changes.

Try making `clickable` field `volatile`. Jeremy Manson has a [great article](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) about `volatile` and other good Java concurrency articles.

I also suggest you to implement what you want the other way - just make the button disabled on first click until your web service gives you a result. Disabled button is a clear message to user that you handled the click and are doing something while it is disabled.

Check also [Happened-before](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before) term on Wikipedia.

Comment: solve the problem in the "dirty" way but im out of time to keep looking for nice solutions. after reading the articles you suggest (great articles in deed, learn a lot about memory management in java and find out the volatile variables) and try a lot of things with memory and threads i just put the "clickable" flag out of the class in a singleton that maintain always the value no matter where it is, not elegant but works and its all i need right now. anyway found your answer very interesting so i set it as right answer and get my vote. thx

Comment: Hmm I wonder why placing 'clickable' flag in singleton should solve the problem if `clickable` is not volatile. Singleton or not it does not matter for concurrency issues. Just put `volatile` keyword in your original code and everything should work fine.

Comment: i try with clickable as volatile and no work, i try another things with threads and nothing, even try to put the class as a singleton in app, just one class, maintained in all app and still the same problems, then i decide just put clickable in app scope and change its value when i need and that work fine, i have tested a lot in many phones and android versions and everything is ok :)

Comment: Well, what can I say, it is great that your problem is solved. But volatile should work too. If it does not, most likely you had some other problems in application code.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you run all of the enable/disable of the clicking functionality on the UI thread , this should work fine .

anyway , you already have a built in API function that is called "[setClickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29)" . why won't you use it ?

Comment: i try with the setClickable function of the button but i have problems with that. it seems that Android (in 2.3.3 version at least) set a queue of "clicks" and even when set the button not clickable the clicks just go ahead so i decide to manage this way

Comment: i see . what if inside the listener you add a check : "if(!isClickable()) return; "  ?

Comment: problem solved, i explain how in a comment in the other answer. thx for the answer and your time.

Comment: i think you are missing something. using setClickable(false) also changes the way it is shown , so the user knows that it cannot be clicked . using your method , the user might think something doesn't work well .

Comment: no I'm blocking the screen with a progress bar...there is no visual problem with what i'm doing, the setClickable is the logical thing to use in this case but don't do what i want to do, if you make 2 quick clicks on a button the button will change to unclickable/disable but the two events will execute

Comment: i see. so this sounds like a bug with the UI of android?

Comment: mmmm don't know, i assume that was the normal behavior of a clickable view and that i have to deal with it, what i know its that i test it enough to see that behavior happens always, with the setClickble and the setEnabled functions, even hiding the button, of course i have intensive code execution in the onclick, maybe with simple execution works fine, i make a search and found someone with the same issue and the solution that he suggest was similar the one i implement, the override of the onClick with the flag.

Comment: ok , thanks for the info . wonder how come i've never seen this behavior.